# The name 'file' does not exist in the current context.. Third line

Tags: c#

```
foreach (var file in files)

File.Move(File.FullName, ConvertToUnsign(file.Fullame.ToLower().Replace("'", String.Empty).Replace("-", String.Empty)));
```

It is giving me an error for 'file' here

```
lstNames.Add(file.Name.Replace(".jpg", String.Empty));
return lstNames;
```

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - If that was missing, he would be seeing the error earlier that reported.

Comment: @DangerZone Leaving out brackets alone is not an error; Not using them simply just uses **the first line** after the `foreach` statement.

Comment: @IanH. - I **fully** know what missing brackets do, hence why I upvoted your answer... But are you aware of the comment I was even replying to? (which seems to have been deleted)

Comment: @DangerZone I was assuming the comment you replied to had something to do with leaving out the brackets and you were saying that that was an error. I am sorry if I misunderstood something ><

Comment: @IanH. - It was about adding `using System.IO;`, which, if missing, would have hinted at something wrong on the `File.Move(...)` line rather than the specified line.

Comment: @DangerZone Ah that makes sense. I apologize for missassuming the situation. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the curly braces in your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    File.Move(File.FullName, ConvertToUnsign(file.Fullame.ToLower().
                             Replace("'", String.Empty).Replace("-", String.Empty)));
    lstNames.Add(file.Name.Replace(".jpg", String.Empty));
}
return lstNames;
```

In any loop structure, if you don´t enclose the code in curly braces `{}`, the loop only affects to the first line following the loop line. So in this case, the foreach only would affect to the `File.Move`line.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing out the `{ }` brackets.

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    File.Move(File.FullName, ConvertToUnsign(file.Fullame.ToLower().Replace("'", String.Empty).Replace("-", String.Empty)));
    lstNames.Add(file.Name.Replace(".jpg", String.Empty));
}
return lstNames;
```